# $f$ is increasing and concave up, determine definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

[image]

Can you help me? I understand that it has to do with areas. I can draw pictures and unsteratsnd thet the inequality holds. But how to prove it correctly?

Comment: The first inequality follows from the fact that $f$ is increasing, hence $f(a) < f(x)$ if $a < x \leq b$. The second inequality follows from the inequality $f(x) < f(a) + (f(b)-f(a))(x-a)$ for $a < x < b$, which follows from strict convexity of $f$.

Comment: This is a chord I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because $f$ is increasing, we have $f(a)\le f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$. Next see the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality).

The proof of this inequality goes by the basic properties of convexity (i.e. up-concavity). The left part of HH inequality: integrate the affine support at the midpoint. The right part: integrate the chord through $a,b$.

The HH inequality reverts in the case of down-concavity, because $f$ is down concave $\iff -f$ is up concave. Use this variant of HH to prove your inequality. Monotonocity also reverts. The inequalities are strict because of (strict) monotonicity properties.